# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when trying to xUnit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, testing, xunit

I have a class where I implement a timer. I want to make xUnit tests for that class. When i try to run the tests i have the following error

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What i am doing in the constructor shouldn't fixed the specific error? Why not? Can someone explain to me why I got that error?

GuessingGameTimerTests.cs

```
private readonly GuessingGameTimer t;

        public GuessingGameTimerTests(GuessingGameTimer t)
        {
            this.t = t;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void StartTimerTest()
        {
            t.SetTimer(30000);
            bool expected = t.IsEnabled();
            Assert.True(expected);
        }
....
```

GuessingGameTimer.cs

```
public class GuessingGameTimer 
    {
        public event EventHandler OnNumberChanged;
        private System.Timers.Timer NumberGeneratorTimer;
        private int replacetime; // Time in seconds
        private int reSetValue; // Time in seconds

        //constractor starts the timer
        public GuessingGameTimer(int replacetime)
        {
            this.replacetime = replacetime;
            reSetValue = replacetime;
            SetTimer(replacetime);
        }
        public void SetTimer(int replacetime)
        {
            NumberGeneratorTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(replacetime);
            NumberGeneratorTimer.Elapsed += OnTick;
            NumberGeneratorTimer.AutoReset = true;
            NumberGeneratorTimer.Enabled = true;
            this.replacetime = getSeconds();
            reSetValue = getSeconds();
        }
        public void ResetTimer()
        {
            NumberGeneratorTimer.AutoReset = true;
            NumberGeneratorTimer.Enabled = true;
            replacetime = reSetValue;
        }

        public void StopTimer()
        {
            NumberGeneratorTimer.Enabled = false;
        }

        public int getSeconds()
        {
            return replacetime;
        }

        public Boolean IsEnabled()
        {
            return NumberGeneratorTimer.Enabled;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i dont understand why is null. i tried to do something like "private readonly GuessingGameTimer t = GuessingGameTimer(3000)" but still doesnt work

Comment: But then again you are assigning null explicitly in tests constructor. Remember dependency injection is not setup by default in unit tests project. So the constructor parameter will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public GuessingGameTimerTests()
    {
        this.t = new GuessingGameTimer(3000);
    }
```

Comment: tried it before but i got the following error "The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data"

Comment: can you post your complete test class? I cleaned up the constructor parameters as well in answer. Make sure your constructor does not take in any parameters.